# Can hook up this light fixture to a cord?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

Is it possible that this light fixture could have a power cord connected to it? For home use...

[image]

The tag says:

Caution (Please read below):
Factory wiring is for all "on" operation

For switching application: (W/ BDP)
connect red wire to a switched input

For switching application: (W/O BDP)
connect grey/red to a switched input

Other label: 120/277 volts,  model "ibc 454 mv"

[image]

Wiring instructions
[image]

Comment: Looks like there are instructions right there on the tag, too bad I can only read half of it.  If you want to post what it says, you will get a better answer than people just guessing.

Comment: The other label also, it's to blurry. From what I've read *I'd think* you'd want line voltage only on the black wire; red may be for low voltage 'switching'. We'd need the series or model number to confirm. [IBZ?](http://www.lithonia.com/commercial/ibz.html#.VQO9uY6H3Tp)

Comment: Thank you so much for the info.  I added the other label

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth I found this at [texasbowhunter.com](http://discussions.texasbowhunter.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-424468.html) (beware, knowledge gained from random discussions is to be avoided):

> I used the exact same lights on my shop and if you leave that red wire out only half the lights will come on. -Jes

You might want to wait for others opinions; but I'd feel pretty safe powering the black and if only half the lights come on, hook up the red too. Also if it came with them nutted after having been installed somewhere, +1.  But it'd still be nice to confirm this in the installer's manual which I can't find. (Which I see you have but it doesn't match the color scheme? so, erm... call them?)

The half inch knock-out is where you're going to install a [cord relief](https://www.google.com/search?q=1/2%20cord%20relief&biw=1280&bih=888&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=IDoEVeCDG8qWgwT7q4KQCA&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg) in, and then feed the cord through it and back out the rectangle hole to wire it, then shove everything back inside and find a cover plate for it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though it is meant only for house wiring. The opening in the back is not suited for a power cord, as in plug into the wall type cord. If it was, it would have a small round hole for a cable connector to mount into.

Comment: There's definitely more work to be done, but which wire(s) get power?

Comment: I'm sure it's not intended to be a plug in light.  I'm just wondering if there is a hack to make it that way.

Comment: It does have a round hole that I didn't punch out yet.  It's definitely wide than a power cord though

Comment: @user34610 that's the half inch knock-out you're going to install a [cord relief](https://www.google.com/search?q=1/2+cord+relief&biw=1280&bih=888&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=IDoEVeCDG8qWgwT7q4KQCA&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg) in, and then feed the cord through it and back out the rectangle hole to wire it, then shove everything back inside and find a cover plate for it. But we still need (install manual) to know which wires.

Comment: I added the wiring sheet..  Not sure if that is useful..

Comment: I humbly submit, any way a power cord for a wall plug, is used, will be a hack. If you are ok with that, hook it up to the non switched wires the little label suggests. From what I have read so far, route your plug wire through the 1/2" knockout, cut off all the wires at the second plug, bare the ends of wire 3/4", wire nut the grounds together, wire nut the whites together, and combine the red and black, wire nutting it to the black wire from the power cord. All this needs to be done with the access cover removed that is under the bulbs as seen from room side. Testor101, where are you??